# windows 7-start menu folders/subfolders show short cuts/empty

Tags: windows-7, permissions

Upgraded from windows 7 to 10 and rolled back.Start menu folders/subfolders changed to short cuts/empty losing the link to user, changed user permission.Seems to be an issue with security permission for the user/administrator.Is there any solution instead of doing restore for each installed program through properties,permission tabs.